# Confused by Node.js readline on() method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am confused by some simple behavior I see from `readline on()` method.

I have a file called `small.csv` which looks like this:

```
Date,Close
2015-11-12,2045.97
2015-11-11,2075.00
2015-11-10,2081.72
2015-11-09,2078.58
```

I wrote this script:

**my.js**

```
var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('small.csv')
});

global.myarray = [];
rl.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log('Line from file:', line);
  global.myarray.push(line);
});

console.log(global.myarray);
// done
```

Script Output:

```
dan@nia111:~/d1d2p $ 
dan@nia111:~/d1d2p $ node -v
v5.0.0
dan@nia111:~/d1d2p $ 
dan@nia111:~/d1d2p $ 
dan@nia111:~/d1d2p $ node my.js
[]
Line from file: Date,Close
Line from file: 2015-11-12,2045.97
Line from file: 2015-11-11,2075.00
Line from file: 2015-11-10,2081.72
Line from file: 2015-11-09,2078.58
dan@nia111:~/d1d2p $ 
dan@nia111:~/d1d2p $
```

I want to enhance the script so it fills `global.myarray` rather than leaving it empty.

When I step through the script with `node-debug`,
it appears that `global.myarray` is filling but I think that it is an illusion.

Also when I run
`node my.js`
it appears that 
`console.log(global.myarray);`

runs before `small.csv` is read.

So I probably need to understand some asynchronous mechanism at work here.

The following question might be easy for those who understand `readline` well.

But, I'd be happy to get an answer to this question:

**How to enhance `my.js` so it fills `global.myarray` rather than leaving it empty?**

Comment: The event `line` is async

Comment: Because you code is async you have to listen to the [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close)  event (`[...]emitted when the input stream receives its "end" event[...]`) and inside that callback you have your final result of `myarray`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of it's asynchronous nature Node.js can be a bit tricky with this kind of things. It means that when your code is executing, it is firing the `rl.on('line')` handler and passing to the next call which in our case is the `console.log`. The problem in your actual code is not that the array is not filling up, it's that you are expecting it to be populated to early. Here is an example of how you could fix your problem:

```
var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('small.csv')
});

global.myarray = [];
rl.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log('Line from file:', line);
  global.myarray.push(line);
});

rl.on('close', function () {
    console.log(global.myarray);
});
```

In this piece of code, when there is no more line to read from, the `console.log` will be called and there will be some data displayed.